# How does allmyapps.com work on Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

The question describes everything, how does [allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/) work? With a single click (like iPhone app store), you click on install and my system asks me "DO you want to install?"

In contrast to regular installation, we 1st download the .exe or .deb and install it.

So, how is it possible via web?

I think, I am missing out on something very basic, but can some one please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MrStatic explained, it is done through magnet urls. The website actually links to

```
apt:packagename?section=universe?section=multiverse
 ^         ^           ^
 Use apt   |           Repository section to use
           |
           Name of the package to install.
```

when clicking install instead of an http:// - url which leads to a downloadable package.

Also check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme for more information

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu atleast

> About the installation process
>
> The installation process is completely secure. is installed through the official Ubuntu packaging system, from the official secured repositories. In case the application is already installed on your computer, a warning message will appear and no installation will occur.

Comment: Can you please explain technically how that works? XML?

Comment: The ubuntu installer has magnet urls. Like email/torrents/whatnot